# Showing ViewPager within a RelativeLayout (LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

My ViewPager is contained within a RelativeLayout in my listview_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the pager item for the ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/template_swipeup"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is where I set up the adapter:

```
private void init(Context context) {
    View view = inflate(context, R.layout.listview_item, this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter;
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
```

**Edit:**

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.template_shirt_1000_1500_overlay, R.drawable.template_leggings_1000_1500_overlay};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public CustomPagerAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view == (RelativeLayout) o);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageview.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
```

}

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: make your viewpager parent as LinearLayout and try

Comment: plz paste your  listview_item.xml

Comment: you are casting linear layout into the relative layout.

Comment: post your view pager adapter class

Comment: I want it to be in a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are casting linear layout into the relative layout.

you uses

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
return (view == (RelativeLayout) o);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object   object) {
container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
```

instead of that you have to use

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
return (view == (LinearLayout) o);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object   object) {
container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

I am not sure. But try once.

Comment: Okay this actually worked. Basically it's the opposite of the the containing layout type. Interesting. Need to look at that more closely next time.

Comment: yeah dude. Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 1):

Change your below method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
      return (view == (RelativeLayout) o);
 }
```

To:

```
@Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
      return (view == (LinearLayout) o);
 }
```

And also below one:

```
 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
 }
```

To:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post again. My listview_item.xml is huge so I only posted part of it. Basically that RelativeLayout is inside a LinearLayout, which would make a difference I suppose.